# Dataframe export to excel - save data format

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-excel, dataformat

I am trying to save the data format of the dataframe I am exporting to excel.

I've styled it using 'style.format' to have the appropriate columns be currency and percentage.

However, when I export to excel it doesn't retain the style I am trying to retain for the columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using openpyxl package. It supports various excel styles through openpyxl.styles